# gemsonrails failing with

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Environment: Ubuntu.

I have followed the [instructions](http://gemsonrails.rubyforge.org/) thusly:

```
$ sudo gem install gemsonrails
```

This runs successfully.

It fails on this step:

```
$ cd rails_app_folder 
$ gemsonrails
```

This fails because `gemsonrails` is not on the path. However runnings `gemsonrails` like so:

```
/blahblah/gemsonrails
```

Yields the following error message:
    : No such file or directory

Trying to run it from the gem's `bin` directory and attempting to supply a `rails_root` option gives the same error.

Ideas?

Comment: I also have this problem.

$ /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/gemsonrails-0.7.2/bin/gemsonrails 
: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

I gave up on gemsonrails and instead:

1) In your config/enviroment.rb, add a line

```
  config.gem "icalendar"
```

2) run

```
rake gems:unpack GEM=icalendar
```

then take a peek in vendor/gems/